# How do I initialize a new column in a data frame using data from two other columns and some decisions?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I'm trying to add a new column to which is calculated from some simple decisions I've attempted to place in a function.

```
calculateNewValue <- function(a, b)
{
    if(a == b)
        result <- 4
    if(a >= b * 2)
        result <- 2;
    if(a > b)
        result <- 3;
    if(a < b)
        result <- 5;
    if(a * 2 <= b)
        result <- 6;
    return(result);    
}
data.set$newCol <- calculateNewValue(data.set$colA, data.set$colB);
```

Here is what my sample data looks like:

```
Name    colA    colB
S1       4       4
S2       4       3
S3       4       5
S4       4       8
```

Based on my function, the results I expect to see in newCol are:

```
4
3
5
6
```

However, the result I actually get is:

```
4
4
4
4
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: FYI, `ifelse()` is Vectorized

Comment: you can do `Vectorized(calculateNewValue)(data.set$colA, data.set$colB)`

Comment: The way your function is written, you need some `else`. When `b` is positive, your `if (a >= b * 2)` results will be overwritten by `if(a > b)` results. You could fix by changing all but your first `if` to `else if`, or by changing your `result <- ...` to `return(...)`, so that the function is stopped as soon as a positive condition is hit. But the real fix, as Sotos suggests, is to use *nested* `ifelse` statements, which are vectorized so you also won't need to mess with `Map` or `apply` as the current answers are suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your function. You need to apply it to the data frame in an iterative manner.

With `Map` or `mapply` function,  you can do:

```
# using Map function
df$newCol <- unlist(Map(calculateNewValue, df$colA, df$colB))
print(df)

  Name colA colB newCol
1   S1    4    4      4
2   S2    4    3      3
3   S3    4    5      5
4   S4    4    8      6

# another one using mapply
df$newCol <- mapply(calculateNewValue, df$colA, df$colB)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for breaking that down so simply for me!  using the mapply line exactly as you specified did the trick for me

Comment: `unlist (Map ...)` is the same as `mapply`

Answer (score 1):

`ifelse` is vectorized:

```
calculateNewValue <- function(a, b)
{
    ifelse(a == b, 4,
      ifelse(a >= b * 2, 2,
        ifelse(a > b, 3,
          ifelse(a * 2 < b, 6,
            ifelse(a < b, 5)))))
}    

# now this should work fine:
data.set$newCol <- calculateNewValue(data.set$colA, data.set$colB)
```

I switched the order of the last two conditions to make the stricter one come first.

Answer (score 0):

You will se the problem if you try to run your function with vectors. The way you wrote ir, it only compares only element against another.

```
calculateNewValue(c(4,4), c(4,3))
[1] 4
Warning messages:
1: In if (a == b) result <- 4 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (a >= b * 2) result <- 2 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (a > b) result <- 3 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (a < b) result <- 5 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (a * 2 <= b) result <- 6 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

You have to apply your function to each row separately to get your desired output. Using @Manish answer

```
df$newCol <- unlist(Map(calculateNewValue, df$colA, df$colB))
```